# jQuery Smooth Scroll + Navigation Update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there is a plugin like this, but I'm not sure exactly what it's called so I can't seem to find it. Basically, I'm looking to have a smooth scroll single website with a fixed navbar at the top and the current page updates in the navbar as you scroll to that section.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to something like this?

http://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/

Check this out:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Or you may want to check out Twitter Bootstrap:

Observe how the links on the side changes as you scroll down on this page (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ or
http://www.theredspace.com/)

For more information, check out:
http://getbootstrap.com/